# Dense subset of cut locus

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given a complete Riemannian manifold $M$ and point $p\in M$, denote $\mathrm{Cut}_p$ the [cut locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cut_locus_(Riemannian_manifold)) of $p$ and $\mathrm{Cut}_p^1\subset \mathrm{Cut}_p$ the set of points $q$ which are connected to $p$ by more than one length minimising geodesic. According to a remark in Sakai's Riemannian geometry book (Rmk. 4.9), the latter forms a dense subset - but I don't understand why.

**Question:** Why is  $\mathrm{Cut}_p^1\subset \mathrm{Cut}_p$ dense?

---

(I use density in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21295/smoothness-of-distance-function-in-riemannian-manifolds/332219#332219) answer on MO. Comments on how to avoid this property to prove regularity of Riemannian distance function are also very welcome.)

Comment: Does it help to note that the points in $\text{Cut}_p$ that are not in $\text{Cut}^1_p$ must all be points conjugate to $p$?

Comment: I had thought about this as well. In other words, if $v\in T_pM$ satisfies $\exp_p(v) \in \mathrm{Cut}_p\backslash  \mathrm{Cut}^1_p$, then $d \exp_p$ is singular  at $v$. What we  need however, is that $\exp_p$ fails to be injective in every neighbourhood of $v$ - but of course this sort of converse of the inverse function theorem fails in general. And I don't know what to do with the information otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user *Chee* kindly pointed out to me in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21295/smoothness-of-distance-function-in-riemannian-manifolds/332219#332219) on MO one can use the following result from Klingenberg's Riemannian geometry book (Theorem 2.1.12):

**Theorem.** On a complete Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, if $\mathrm{ker}(d\exp_p\vert_v)\neq 0$ for some $(p,v)\in TM$, then $\exp_p$ fails to be injective in every neighbourhood of $v$.

(Thus if injectivity fails infinitesimally, it also fails in every neighbourhood. This is of course false for a general smooth map.)

Now to conclude, take $x \in \mathrm{Cut}_p\backslash \mathrm{Cut}_p^1$, and note that $x=\exp_p(v)$ for some $v\in T_pM$ with $\mathrm{ker}(d\exp_p\vert_v)\neq 0$ (cf. Petersen Lemma 5.78). Take a sequence of opens $U_1\supset U_2\supset\dots\subset T_pM$ with $\bigcap U_n=\{v\}$, then according to the theorem above $\exp_p$ fails to be injective on each $U_n$ and thus $\exists x_n\in \mathrm{Cut}_p^1\cap\exp_p{U_n}$. Clearly $x_n\rightarrow x$ and thus we have proved the density $\mathrm{Cut}^1_p\subset \mathrm{Cut}_p$.